# I can go to my ssd through the terminal

Tags: linux

I got a new notebook(inspiron 5480, Windows 10) and I installed Ubuntu 18.04 over Windows in my SSD.

I got this:

```
$ sudo lhw -short -C disk
```

got:

```
/0/1/0.0.0 /dev/sda disk 1TB (this is my /home)
/0/2/0.0.0 /dev/sdb disk 128GB (this is my root /)
```

But when I want to install conda and other programs I have to use, I can't get to the SSD (128GB disk) through my terminal. I would like to maintain all the programs only in my SSD and not in my hhd.

I follow some tutorials and make all according to the tutorials, but I can use my SSD with my terminal.

There are any way I need to go to modify this issue?

Comment: "I can't get to the ssd through my terminal" - what does that mean exactly? Can't you access your root directory? Is it a permissions problem? Please clarify by editing your question and adding the relevant information.

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk`? From what I understand so far, all of your programs will already be installed to your SSD (where /usr, /bin, var, etc. are) , unless you specifically install something in /home.